# Using a variable in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to put a small collection of simple scripts together for PowerShell to make life easier but am having some problems with variables in these scripts.

In a Linux environment I would use a variable in my scripts (usually $1, $2, etc....) like this to make things easier

```
sed -i 's/$1/$2/g' filename.conf
```

So that all I would need to do is this

```
./findreplace.sh old new filename.conf
```

In powershell, I want to achieve similar, specifically with this command:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership account.name | select name
```

In this case, the $1 would be where 'user.name' is, so that I would be doing:

```
 .\groups.ps1 user.name
```

Is there the facility for this?

Comment: `$1` -> `$args[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Groups.ps1 should have the following content:

```
param( $user )

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Select Name
```

You can then invoke it as shown, or as `.\Groups.ps1 -user user.name`.

However, I'd probably try to do it as an "advanced command", and allow it to handle multiple names, and also names passed in via the pipeline:

```
[CmdletBinding()]

param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true;ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias("Identity","sAMAccountName")
    string[] $Users
)

PROCESS {
    ForEach ($User in $Users) {
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User | Select Name
    }
}
```

which would also allow you to do something like `Get-ADUser | .\Groups.ps1`

Comment: So the first code comment works exactly as I would expect, only difference is that I do not use the '-user' part, instead just using: .\Groups.ps1 user.name.

Comment: The second code block throws up a load of errors :(

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? It seems that not all AD objects are created equal, and I've had some problems using ADPrincipals where ADUsers are expected...

Comment: Major 5, Minor 1, Build 14393, Revision 1944

Comment: If you do the pipeline version, it _may_ stop throwing errors if you do `(Get-ADUser).samaccountname | .\Groups.ps1` (obviously, you can add parameters and filters to the `Get-ADUser` _inside_ the parens - but don't pipe inside the parens)

Answer (score 1):

You can add for loop form example script above:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args.Length; $i++) { Set-Variable -Scope Script -Name ($i + 1) -Value $args[$i] }

Write-Host "1: $1"
Write-Host "2: $2"
```

But more easy is just to declare script parameter as:

```
param($1, $2)

Write-Host "1: $1"
Write-Host "2: $2"
```

By the way it's bad practice to declare variables as numbers.